# Run script at shutdown/reboot with systemd

Tags: script, shutdown, reboot, systemd

I would like to run a script file when the system is called for shutdown/ reboot from 'reboot' and 'shutdown' commands. And if possible, also hard shutdowns like 'init 0' or 'poweroff'. How would I go about doing that? A config file or command would be nice. I use `systemd` instead of `initscripts`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copy / link the script into your /etc/init.d/rc0.d (HALT) and /etc/init.d/rc6.d (reboot)  directories, and make sure it's name is prefixed with: "K20"

FYI: http://www.linux.com/news/enterprise/systems-management/8116-an-introduction-to-services-runlevels-and-rcd-scripts

Comment: I use systemd instead of initscripts. Know a different way to do that without using initscripts? Sorry that wasnt in my post

Comment: The [How Do I Convert A SysV Init Script Into A systemd Service File?](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/systemd-for-admins-3.html) page explains the basics, just add the appropriate **WantedBy=**  targets to your service file e.g.
[Install]
WantedBy=final.target   /   halt.target  /  shutdown.target

Comment: For examples see:  [archlinux - systemd/Services](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Services)