# How can I trigger a process on start (boot) and stop (shutdown, reboot) using systemd units?

Tags: boot, systemd

Similar, but not identical to [Run script at shutdown/reboot with systemd](https://superuser.com/q/513161/964771):

I want to run a custom process using `systemd` when the system is going down (shutdown or reboot, maybe panic also), and when the system is booting.
Both actions should be run as early as possible.

Obviously the `Type` of service will be a `oneshot`, but I'm unsure about the rest (`Wants`, `Before`, `After`, `WantedBy`, etc.).

As my process needs the journal, I had added (among others):

```systemd
[Unit]
DefaultDependencies=no
Wants=syslog.target
After=local-fs.target exit.target
Before=multi-user-target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=no

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When having enabled the service, my program is started (via `ExecStart=`) after local filesystems are mounted, but it is immediately started again (via `ExecStop=`) before temporary files are being created.
On reboot it was not started at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After multiple iterations I found this solution involving **two** units; one used for booting, and another used for shutting down:

```systemd
# /etc/systemd/system/log-start-test.service
[Unit]
Description=Test Start log entries
Documentation=man:logger(1)
Documentation=https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/bootup.html
DefaultDependencies=no
After=local-fs.target
Before=sysinit.target
Requires=local-fs.target
ConditionPathExists=/usr/bin/logger

[Service]
Type=oneshot
TimeoutSec=5
ExecStart=/usr/bin/logger -p user.notice "Starting test..."

[Install]
WantedBy=sysinit.target
```

The start is logged shortly after the local filesystems were mounted (as requested).

```systemd
# /etc/systemd/system/log-stop-test.service
[Unit]
Description=Test Stop log entries
Documentation=man:logger(1)
Documentation=https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/bootup.html
DefaultDependencies=no
After=default.target
Requires=local-fs.target
ConditionPathExists=/usr/bin/logger

[Service]
Type=oneshot
TimeoutSec=5
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStop=/usr/bin/logger -p user.notice "Stopping Test..."

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

The stop message is logged after the first few serviced were terminated (concurrently ran with them I guess).

The `TimeoutSec=5` is there, just to make sure a hanging process won't prevent booting or stopping, and most likely it makes no sense for `logger`.